# swift tableView is nil

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

So every time I add a new entry to Firebase in the addItemViewController it segues back to ViewController but when doing this the app crashes and with this error:
"**Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value**".
The error is on the line in ViewController.swift in ViewDidLoad with tableView.reloadData(). Any suggestions would be much appreciated! Thanks!

ViewController.swift

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  toDo
//
//  Created by Jesse Brior on 10/5/18.
//  Copyright © 2018 Jesse Brior. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import Firebase

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var ref : DatabaseReference!
    var items: [itemObjectModel] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        ref = Database.database().reference()
        tableView.reloadData()
        self.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated: true)
        self.title = "To Do's"
        storeKeys()
    }

    func storeKeys() {
        ref.child("tasks").queryOrdered(byChild: "completed").observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
            var newItems: [itemObjectModel] = []
            for child in snapshot.children {
                if let snapshot = child as? DataSnapshot,
                    let newTask = itemObjectModel(snapshot: snapshot) {
                    newItems.append(newTask)
                    self.items = newItems
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
            self.items = newItems
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        })
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return items.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        let item = items[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = item.name.capitalized
        if item.completed {
            cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "Complete"
        }else{
            cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "Incomplete"
        }
        return cell
    }

}
```

addItemViewController.swift

```
//
//  addItemController.swift
//  toDo-v2
//
//  Created by Jesse Brior on 10/9/18.
//  Copyright © 2018 Jesse Brior. All rights reserved.
//

import Foundation
import UIKit
import Firebase

class addItemController: UIViewController {

    var ref : DatabaseReference!
    @IBOutlet weak var addItemField: UITextField!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        ref = Database.database().reference()
        self.title = "Add Item"
    }
    @IBAction func addItemPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        if addItemField.text != "" {
            let task = addItemField.text!
            let completion = false

            let newItem = itemObjectModel(name: task, completed: completion)

            let newItemRef = self.ref.child("tasks").child(task.lowercased())
            newItemRef.setValue(newItem.toAnyObject())
        }
        self.present(ViewController(), animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

link to pic of crash log: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZGC4k.png

Comment: Set the Exception Breakpoint to get the actual line where the exception occurs. Most likely the error reason is the arbitrary instance of `ViewController()` which is **not** the instance in the storyboard.

Comment: Why would you call `tableView.reloadData()` in `viewDidLoad` before you actually add data to the `items` list?

Answer (score 0):

You error is in this line:

```
self.present(ViewController(), animated: true, completion: nil)
```

That does not as you put it 'segue back' to you `ViewController` class but it creates a new instance of it and presents that.  Also as it is creating a new instance of just the basic class when it should probably be instantiating it from the storyboard/xib file and therefore it does not set up any of the IBOutlets just creates the plain empty class.  So that is why you get the error that `tableview` is nil, nothing has set it up.

You don't show how you present the `addItemController` as that will dictate the correct method to use to return back to your original `ViewController`.

On a slightly separate note you should really use the correct format for class and variable names in Swift.  So `addItemController` is a class and should therefore be called `AddItemController` and in the `ViewController` the `tableview` should really be `tableView`.